# Output is 0 and not what i input

Tags: c

Hello i'm sorry if my question is too easy for you guys, i'm new to c and would like some help. Thank you This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap2();

int main(){
    int x,y;
    printf("SWAP WITH USER INPUT\n");
    printf("Input 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Input 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("Values before swap x = %d and y = %d\n",x,y);
    swap2();
}

 void swap2(){
    int x, y, z;
    z = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    printf("Values after swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x,y);
 }
```

My question is why does `x` and `y` at the after part is `0` and not what i input and how do i fix it?

Comment: `int x, y, z;` in `swap2` are *local*, *uninitialized variables*; should be at least `void swap2(int x, int y){int z; ...}`  (may be `void swap2(int &x, int &y){...`) and `swap2(x, y);` in `main`

Comment: Read about local variables and scope in your favourite book.

Comment: I think you need to go back to whatever text-book or tutorial you're reading, or class you're attending, because you have missed some very basic things about scope and variables.

Comment: After the declaration `int x, y, z;` *What are the values of `x, y & z`?*

Answer (score 2):

Please, note, that in your current implementation

```
 void swap2() {
   /* Local variables declarations */
   /* x, y, z are not from main    */
   int x, y, z;
   ...
 }
```

`x`, `y` and `z` are *local* *uninitialized* values; so you swap *trash* (all chances that `x == y == z == 0`). If you want to *swap* `x` and `y` values which are declared in `main`, you can operate with *pointers*, not *values*:

```
 int main() {
   ...
   printf("Values before swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x, y);
   /* Addresses of x and y */
   swap2(&x, &y);
   /* Now x and y swapped their values */
   printf("Values after swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x, y);
 }

 /* swap2 wants addresses of x and y, not their values */
 void swap2(int* x, int* y) {
     int z;  

     z = *x; /* z get a value at address of x      */
    *x = *y; /* put value at y address to x adress */
    *y = z;  /* put z at y address                 */ 
 }
```

**Outcome:**

```
 Values before swap x = 3 and y = 4
 Values after swap x = 4 and y = 3
```

If `swap2` should do nothing but print values in *different order*, just let it do it:

```
 int main() {
   ...
   printf("Values before swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x, y);
   /* we don't swap x, y but pring them in different order; no need in pointers */
   swap2(x, y);
 }

 void swap2(int x, int y) {
   /* swap x and y within printf */
   printf("Values after swap x = %d and y = %d\n", y, x); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in swap2. In swap2, x and y are private to the function, having no relation to the x and y in main. So, you should pass x and y to the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap2(int x, int y);
int main(){
    int x,y;
    printf("SWAP WITH USER INPUT\n");
    printf("Input 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Input 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("Values before swap x = %d and y = %d\n",x,y);
    swap2(x, y);
}

void swap2(int x, int y){
    int  z;
    z = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    printf("Values after swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x,y);
 }
```

Plus, you don't need stdlib.h.

Comment: Is there a difference between calling them private or local?

Comment: @RobertS the term to be used here is _local_ rather than _private_ .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you did not know that a variable declared and defined like that in `main()` is not accessible from functions calling by `main()` automatically and not to define them new to access the desired values.

You need to provide a calling function the required values (or at least pointers to them) to operate with those as arguments by the call of it, to use them inside there.

`swap2()` doesn´t get `x` and `y` from your `main()` as arguments. you are declaring again different local variables of swap2 for `x` and `y`, which do not have the value assigned to from `main()`, just because it are other variables.

```
void swap2()              // No incoming values as arguments
{
   int x, y, z;           // You declaring here new local variables of x and y for swap2()
   z = x;
   x = y;
   y = z;
   printf("Values after swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x,y);
}
```

Use it like that:

```
void swap2(int x, int y) 
{
   int z;

   z = x;
   x = y;
   y = z;

   printf("Values after swap x = %d and y = %d\n", x,y);
}
```

and put the line

```
swap2(x,y);
```

inside your `main()`, instead of

```
swap2();
```

Hopefully, you have learned something new now ;-)

Comment: way better than my explanation :-) god job